# error with IPython in showing plots with pyqtgraph

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, anaconda, jupyter, pyqtgraph

i have successfully installed `pyqtgraph`  library in python 2.7. I forked latest project from GitHub and then `python setup.py install`. I am now trying to show plots with it. I open a python terminal and start typing the following:-

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
```

All of these commands are successfully interpreted.
But then i run the command to see the plot as:-

```
pg.plot(x, y, symbol='o')
```

It outputs:

```
<pyqtgraph.graphicsWindows.PlotWindow at 0x6b7f708>
```

And then a windows titled `pythonw` opens and says 'not responding' and hangs and i am unable to see any output. After long time window crashes and terminal says:

```
Kernel died, restarting
```

What could be the error? Should i have installed using .exe?

**EDIT:**
As pointed out below by titusjan, the problem is with the default Jupyter/Ipython notebook shipping with Anaconda which i have not been able to correct. There must be some installation problem. And i am working on Windows.

Comment: Looks like the IPython kernel has crashed. What happens if you enter the statements in the regular Python prompt?

Comment: @titusjan I actually ran now in the regular python prompt as you said and it worked! I don't understand why? Can you tell me why IPython crashed and what i can do to remedy this? I am using Anaconda 4.1.1 on Windows 64-bit. I want to get my IPython up and running.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know; I don't know much about IPython. I have added the IPython tag to this post so the IPython experts might see it. It's probably a good idea if you edit it to include the IPython version you use.

Comment: I am using the default Jupyter notebook shipped by default with Anaconda 4.1.1 and i am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyqtgraph` plots functions based on PyQT GUI-based programming. So the task of displaying plots have to be treated as starting a GUI. As told above, when I feed the commands to the IPython terminal, it works out fine:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
```

As noted above, problem starts when i feed  the line:

```
pg.plot(x, y, symbol='o')
```

To remedy this: either input these 2 lines in one go

```
pg.plot(x, y, symbol='o')
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

or immediately after the previous line `pg.plot(x, y, symbol='o')` input this line:

```
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

Alternatively we could use the default QT-GUI commands also. So we get correct plots even if we run this code:-

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui 
import sys

x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
pg.plot(x, y, symbol='o')
if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

However, if one wants to avoid invoking QTGui methods explicitly, assuming one has saved the below code as `xyz.py`, one can run the code successfully displaying the graphics by writing on the command line: `pythonw -i xyz.py`. This ensures that python has been explicitly asked to run in interactive mode. `pythonw` is for running in windows.

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
pg.plot(x, y, symbol='o')
```