# PyqtGraph when used in Python 3.5 causes the kernel to die unexpectedly in Windows

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, python-3.5, spyder, pyqtgraph

I am successfully able to import pyqtgraph but when I run my code,the kernel dies unexpectedly.I am using Python 3.5 in Spyder. Even after going through this link [error-with-ipython-in-showing-plots-with-pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337351/error-with-ipython-in-showing-plots-with-pyqtgraph) still the kernel dies .I already have Qt4 and pyqt4 installed.Kindly help.

Comment: Please see [this comment](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4349#issuecomment-293446015). Hope it helps in your case.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I have seen the code but it utilises Qtwidgets from Pyqt5 so does it mean that I need to update Pyqt4 to Pyqt5 as pyqtgraph is compatible with pyqt4 only after checking the documentation.Kindly help as I am new to pyqtgraph.